# Sistema de Login em Python

Tags: python

Quando errar o valor de uma váriavel, como faço para ele retornar ja que no caso o valor foi digitado errado!

```
usuario     =   str(input('Qual seu usuário de Login? :'))
if  usuario ==  'walter':
    print('Usuário correto!')
    print(' ')
else:
    print('Usuário Incorreto!')
    print(' ')
senha   = str(input('Qual e sua senha de Login? :'))
if  senha   ==  'walter':
    print('Senha correta!')
    print(' ')
else:
    print('Senha Incorreta!')
    print(' ')
```

Comment: Você quer que o programa pergunte denovo a senha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar um while para fazer isso, para não te dar a resposta inteira vou criar um exemplo em que você queira comparar duas variáveis e quer que o programa fique rodando enquanto elas não sejam iguais.

Irei criar uma função auxiliar para verificar as variáveis:

```py
def compara_variaveis(variavel_um, variavel_dois):
    return variavel_um == variavel_dois
```

Após isso irei fazer um loop que pergunte uma palavra para o usuário e enquanto a comparação for falsa ele não deva parar de perguntar:

```py
palavra_correta = 'batata'
palavra_usuario = input('Digite a sua palavra: ')

while compara_variaveis(palavra_correta, palavra_usuario) is False:
    palavra_usuario = input('Ops... Palavra errada, digite novamente a sua palavra: ')

print('Você acertou!')
```

Note que a impressão de tela dizendo que acertou só acontece após a verificação ser verdadeira.
Agora basta pensar um pouquinho em como você pode aplicar isso no seu problema!

Comment: Deu tudo certo, ainda não entendi muito sobre o código mas ja me ajudou muito obrigado !

Comment: Que bom, se puder marque a resposta como correta :)